# How to get list of StaticMesh from path?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I am trying to get list of Staticmesh from the specific path and set the Staticmesh to RootComponent. Please help on this issues. Code is below;

```
 TArray<UObject*> MeshAssets;    
 EngineUtils::FindOrLoadAssetsByPath(TEXT("/Game/StarterContent/Meshs/"), MeshAssets, EngineUtils::ATL_Regular);
 StaticMeshComponent->SetStaticMesh(MeshAssets.GetData);
 StaticMeshComponent->AttachTo(RootComponent);
```

The Error is

> Error    2    error C3867: 'TArray::GetData': function call missing argument list; use '&TArray::GetData' to create a
>   pointer to member<

Answer (score 0):

`StaticMeshComponent->SetStaticMesh(MeshAssets.GetData);`

You're calling a function without the `( )` and possible parameters.

`StaticMeshComponent->SetStaticMesh( MeshAssets.GetData( ) );`

should work depending on whether there also have to be any parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Some problems with your code:

- Your Array is of type UObject*, but you need objects with the type UStaticMesh* for your component. The SetStaticMesh-method does not UObject* as parameter.
- You can only set one item from your array as the mesh of your component, e.g. MeshAssets[0].
- GetData is a method, not a variable. You have to call MeshAssets.GetData() if you want to use it.

So, your code should look more like this:

```
TArray<UObject*> MeshAssets;
EngineUtils::FindOrLoadAssetsByPath(TEXT("/Game/StarterContent/Meshs/"), MeshAssets, EngineUtils::ATL_Regular);
for (auto asset : MeshAssets) {
    UStaticMesh* mesh = Cast<UStaticMesh>(asset);
    if (mesh != nullptr) {
        // do something with the mesh, create a component with it, etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: you might want to include a non >= c++11 version :)

Comment: Which part should I change? I was under the impression that you can not compile UE4 without also supporting C++11 features, maybe I am wrong. According to this: https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/Development/CodingStandard/index.html#c++11andmodernlanguagesyntax the engine  code should support things like the auto keyword.

Comment: my bad they upgraded to Visual Studio 13

Comment: Thanks, now it compiles successfully, but couldn't able to get the mesh. I think the program flow couldn't able go into for loop section. How do I can check the MeshAssets does contains some mesh???

Comment: You can set a breakpoint on the for loop and then view the value of MeshAssets in the debugger. Of course, you should also make sure the directory exists and does have the assets inside.

Comment: If you are unable to debug it then you can always just create a UPROPERTY of type UStaticMesh* in your actor and then set the value with blueprints. That way you do not have to use the FindOrLoadAssetsByPath function or do any casting.

Comment: I have set a breakpoint and I've got the value of MeshAssets is  "MeshAssets {AllocatorInstance={Data=0x0000000000000000 <NULL> } ArrayNum=0 ArrayMax=0 } " I think it doesn't load the asset into MeshAssets.

Comment: Then your path must be wrong. You might have a typing error in there (Meshs instead of Meshes).